# Prove that $T$ is surjective.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Assume $X$,$Y$ are Banach spaces, $T \in L(X, Y)$ and

\begin{array}{l}
\exists M>0 \quad \text { s.t. }  \forall  y \in Y \text { , } \exists x \in X \\
\quad y=T x,\|x\| \leqslant M \cdot\|y\|
\end{array}
Prove that $T$ is surjective ?  
we have that  $\forall  y \in Y \text { , } \exists x \in X $ $y= Tx$ so $T$ is surjective . 
is it true ?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich By assumption

Comment: your original proof is correct. Sorry, I didn't read the question carefully, thought it was something else not entirely trivial. It's a very strange problem - you're given that $T$ is surjective plus more, and asked to show $T$ is surjective...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you!!! sir

Comment: @bapob Are you sure the problem is as you have written it?  If so, it is completely trivial.

Comment: @Ramiro This  problem is about to prove the equivalance . But I  wrote just  one side of the problem